# How do I echo output with variable in different line

Tags: php, output, echo

I have the code which uses `str_split()` on `12345678910` to return `12 34 56 78 91 0`.

My problem is when I try to update the database, the wrong data is updated.

I echo it out on the page and the wrong data is outputted.

Also, how do I resolve this?

Here is my code:

```
require("init.php");
$code = "12345678910";
$type = "2";
$disp = str_split($code, $type); 
for($b = 0; $b<$type; $b++){
    $show = "$disp[$b]";
}
for($c = $qty; $c<sizeof($disp); $c++){
    $play = "$disp[$c]"; 
    $id = "7"; 
    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE prmo SET details='$show$play' WHERE id=$id");
    echo "<br/>$show";
    echo "<br/>$play";
}
```

my result with the current code is `56
 34 
78
 34
 91 
34 0 34` expected to be `12 34 56 78 91 0` can  i really achieve this?

Comment: why are you using double quote in here `$show = "$disp[$b]";` !?

Comment: I started with it should i remove it to fixed my problem?

Comment: What is `$qty`? it is not in your posted code block. Is this just to limit the array length? Just use `array_slice()`.  ...but you aren't using `show` anyhow -- so you should remove it from your question ...or is that a typo and `$how` means `$show`? What is the output that you are currently receiving?  What is your expected set of queries using the input string? Please show your expected queries with the variables replaced with the actual values to clarify your question.

Comment: Please return to your question and add the many necessary details to rescue this page.  If you do not improve your question soon, it will risk collecting downvotes and it will be closed as "Off-topic: Why isn't this code working?".

Comment: This really not just working to my level knowledge of php am comfus do checkup on your server with the current code to see my meaning

Comment: I cant achiev this?

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing wrong here is, You are traversing from 2 loops. You only need on loop. try below code:

```
$code = "12345678910";
$type = "2";
$disp = str_split($code, $type); 
for($c = 0; $c<sizeof($disp); $c++){
    $show = $disp[$c];
    $c++;
    $play = $disp[$c]; 
    $id = "7"; 
    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE prmo SET details='$show$play' WHERE id=$id");
    echo $show." ";
    echo $play." ";
}
```